# Scala Type-Inference For Type Constructor

Tags: generics, scala, type-inference, higher-kinded-types, gadt

I have a question regarding type-inferencing on Scala's type-constructors.  I'm running Scala 2.9.1...

Suppose I defined Tree:

```
 sealed trait Tree[C[_], A]
 case class Leaf[C[_], A](a: A) extends Tree[C, A]
 case class Node[C[_], A](a: A, c: C[Tree[C, A]]) extends Tree[C, A]
```

And defined a BinaryTree based upon my Tree definition:

```
 type Pair[A] = (A, A)
 type BinaryTree[A] = Tree[Pair, A]
```

I can now define a BinaryTree of integers as such:

```
 val tree: BinaryTree[Int] = Node[Pair, Int](1, (Leaf(2), Leaf(3)))
```

The problem with this is that I have to supply the type parameters whenever I instantiate `Node`.

So if do this:

```
 val tree: BinaryTree[Int] = Node(1, (Leaf(2), Leaf(3)))
```

I get the error:

```
error: no type parameters for method apply: (a: A, c: C[Tree[C,A]])Node[C,A] in 
object Node exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int, (Leaf[Pair,Int], Leaf[Pair,Int]))
 --- because ---
 argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : (Leaf[Pair,Int], Leaf[Pair,Int])
 required: ?C[Tree[?C,?A]]
   val tree: BinaryTree[Int] = Node(1, (Leaf(2), Leaf(3)))
                               ^
```

Is there any way I can coerce the type-checker so that I don't have to explicitly supply the types of `Node`?

Thanks!

---

**Revised After didierd's Comments**

If I'm understanding correctly, the statement

```
 type Pair[A] = (A, A)
```

in my original question doesn't work since this Pair declaration is just syntactic sugar for a Tuple2 type-constructor (which requires two type-parameters).  This causes the type-inferencer to fail.

If I declare my own Pair class (as didierd suggests in his answer), I'm successful in getting the Tree to work correctly.

```
// Assume same Tree/Leaf/Node definition given above
case class MyPair[A](_1: A, _2: A)
type BinaryTree[A] = Tree[MyPair, A]
```

Then I can do this...

```
scala> val t: BinaryTree[Int] = Leaf(3)
t: BinaryTree[Int] = Leaf(3)

scala> val t2: BinaryTree[Int] = Node(1, MyPair(Leaf(2), Leaf(3)))
t2: BinaryTree[Int] = Node(1,MyPair(Leaf(2),Leaf(3)))
```

I know didierd mentioned this solution in passing, but this seems to behave the way I want.  Please let me know what you think!

Comment: Regarding your revised code: it is more akin to @David's solution. Types are not fully inferred, you must type the expression explicitly as BinaryTree[Int]. I think this is quite reasonable. The covariant solution avoids that, but it comes with a price: while covariance is mostly a good thing, it restricts what the class can do. In particular, it works only with types C that are covariants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem to start with with inferring `C[X] = (X,X)`. Suppose you pass `(String, String)` somewhere the compiler expects `C[String]` and must infer `C`, `C[X]` could be `(X, X)`, `(X, String)`, `(String, X)` or even `(String, String)` with `X` phantom.

Having declared an alias `Pair` does not help. I believe you will have to declare `case class Pair[A](_1: A, _2: A)` - granted, inferring `C[X] = Pair[String]` and `X` phantom would still be possible, but fortunately, the compiler does not do that.

Still, when you write `Tree(1, Pair(Leaf(2), Leaf(3))`, it will not infer the `C` in Leaves. I am not very sure why. But anyway, there is no way it could infer it when you simply write `val l = Leaf(2)`.

I think you can get to something by making everything covariant

```
sealed trait Tree[+C[+X], +A]
case class Leaf[+A](a: A) extends Tree[Nothing, A]
case class Node[+C[+X], +A](a: A, c: C[Tree[C,A]]) extends Tree[C,A]
```

with covariance, you remove C from Leaf, so it need not be inferred

```
case class Pair[+A](left: A, right: A)

val tree = Node(1, Pair(Leaf(2), Node(3, Pair(Leaf(3), Leaf(4)))))
tree: Node[Pair,Int] = Node(1,Pair(Leaf(2),Node(3,Pair(Leaf(3),Leaf(4)))))
```

A side remark, would it not make more sense to have

```
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing, Nothing]
```

rather than `Leaf`. With `Leaf`, there are shapes of binary tree that you cannot get.

---

**Update** regarding your comments:

First do not bother too much with the phantom type, I should not have mentioned it. If you define a type `T[X]` and `X` does not appear otherwise in the definition of T, it is called a phantom type. Clever code may be written with that to ensure that some properties are proved at compile time, but this is not the point here.

As a matter of fact, when the scala compiler is given some types T and X, and must infer C, such that C[X] is (a supertype of) T - in my example, that was T = (String, String) and X = String - it will work only if T (or a supertype) is an parametrization of a type with exactly one type parameter. More generally, as many type parameters as the type parameter C has. As C has one and Tuple2 has two (your having defined an alias Pair does not count), it cannot work.

What I tried to point was that, without such a rule, the compiler would have many choices for `C`. If I know `(String, Int)` is a `C[String]`, and that I must guess what `C` is, then I would think `C[X]` is `(X, Int)`. When you write *if passed (String, Int), wouldn't if infer (Any, Any)*, it does not make sense, given that it is trying to infer a type constructor. The answer must be `C[X] = something with X` (except for the possibility that X is phantom). Completely different would be having `Pair[X] = (String, Int)` and having to infer `X`. Then indeed, it would infer `X = Any`. So given C[String] = (String, String), C[X] = (X, String) is as much a solution as C[X] = (X,X) is.

On your second comment regarding `List`, it is the same problem that also exists with `Pair` once you have defined `case class Pair` (third paragraph in the answer above), namely that it will not infer what `C` is when you write `Leaf(2)`, where `C` does not appear. This is where covariance kicks in, dispensing with the parameter C in Leaf, and so the need to infer it.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the first paragraph.  What does X being phantom mean?  If I pass (String, String) somewhere the compiler expects C[String], wouldn't it infer it to (String, String)?  If I passed a (String, Int), wouldn't it infer to (Any, Any)?

Comment: Also, I get a similar error if I use List instead of my type-alias Pair.  Since lists are homogeneous shouldn't it be able to infer the type?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Updated to answer your comments.

Answer (score 3):

The only variation that occurred to me was to annotate the `Pair` argument instead. Other people I'm sure will have other ideas.

```
object BinaryTreeTest {
  sealed trait Tree[C[_], A]
  case class Leaf[C[_], A](a: A) extends Tree[C, A]
  case class Node[C[_], A](a: A, c: C[Tree[C, A]]) extends Tree[C, A]

  type Pair[A] = (A, A)
  type BinaryTree[A] = Tree[Pair, A]

  val p: Pair[Tree[Pair, Int]] = (Leaf(2), Leaf(3))    
  val t: BinaryTree[Int] = Node(1, p)    
}
```